# How agent login using AMI asterisk interface?

Tags: java, asterisk, amazon-ami, agi

The method AgentCallbackLogin was deprecated from the asterisk manager interface (asterisk-java) and i want to manage connection of agent in order to be ready to receive calls from queues or not without using the handset to login ( using  agentLogin (agent)) if somone have an idea about please??

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use AddQueueMember for same purpose

```
core show application AddQueueMember 

  -= Info about application 'AddQueueMember' =- 

[Synopsis]
Dynamically adds queue members. 

[Description]
Dynamically adds interface to an existing queue. If the interface is already
in the queue it will return an error.
This application sets the following channel variable upon completion:
${AQMSTATUS}: The status of the attempt to add a queue member as a text
string.
    ADDED
    MEMBERALREADY
    NOSUCHQUEUE

[Syntax]
AddQueueMember(queuename[,interface[,penalty[,options[,membername[,stateinterface]]]]])
```

For example if you want callback be on number 123456789, you have use

```
AddQueueMember(800,Local/123456789@out/n)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i try it , the agent is added to the queue but he has the state 1 ( AST_DEVICE_NOT_INUSE ) and he is never login ?????

Comment: You have read more about asterisk states and dialplan. That state mean it availible. Dialplan have control WHERE. Hints have be used to put state in other.

Comment: sorry but I am beginner i asterisk but i am blocked since last week :
i create in the file queue.conf :
[fileAttente]
music=default
strategy=ringall
eventwhencalled = yes
eventmemberstatus = yes
timeout=15
retry=1
wrapuptime=0
maxlen = 0
announce-frequency = 0
announce-holdtime = no   

i add an agent member to the queue :